# what are the advantages and disadvantages of auditing mailboxes in exchange server?

Tags: exchange, audit, mailbox

I want to know the pros and the cons of enabling this feature in our exchange server 2010. Primarily we would like to start of with few mailboxes first, I am  aware that the login logos will require some storage space.